# Projeto JSP + netbeans + bower

Tags: jsp, netbeans, bower

Boa tarde pessoal!

Minha dúvida é a seguinte...

tenho um projeto recém criado JSP no netbeans e quero trabalhar com o bower para gerenciar os pacotes do meu front-end.

Onde devo criar a pasta bower_components?

Se ela for criada dentro de web (view) ao gerar o .war será mandado tudo para o servidor, como devo tratar esses arquivos?

Obrigado.